# Is it possible to group all documents with same _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation in which after unwinding an Array field, I get multiple documents with the same _id. How can I count the number of documents with the same id?
This is what I had in mind:
{$group:{
_id:"$_id",
count: {$sum:1}
}}
No answer I've come across groups by the document id itself. Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample documents, your current aggregagtion and your expected result please

Answer (score 0):

you can use $size to count the elements of the array, before/independent of the unwind.  so you don't have to unwind just to count. but assuming the unwind is needed for other reasons you should be able to also count the grouping of a field value that is common to all or count the documents...it depends on what is your goal/approach overall....